# How we can forwarding audio over X11

Tags: audio, xorg, x11-forwarding

I am trying to study X11. It's working fine.

My question is whether there is any option to forward sound over X11. I Googled about this, and found many answers like *Pulse audio*, *pep refs*.

Can we implement that without *pulse-audio* or any  other sound servers ?

Answer (score 0):

In short, no. The X11 protocol doesn't natively support streaming audio. This is very much the unix way of doing things - have small tools that each to one thing well, and combine them. There are other options if you don't want to configure audio services - both rdp and vnc, which could be considered alternatives to a remote X11 desktop, support audio streaming. They have their downsides though, as they are both oriented around a remote desktop - you wouldn't be able to remote a single app like you can with X11.

Comment: how we can use pulse-audio.